# Directly reading soil moisture sensor with microcontroller analog input

Tags: schematics

The original circuit has digital and analog outputs. I don't need digital.  Can you verify that the new circuit is correct?

Original circuit:

[image]

[Image source](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/interfacing-soil-moisture-sensor-with-arduino-uno)

Circuit changed:

[image]

The original circuit is a soil moisture reader for Arduino boards. I would like to make a reader for the humidity probe that only returns the analog reading. For that, I don't think I need the LM393.

The humidity probe reader is like the image below:

[image]

[Image source](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/interfacing-soil-moisture-sensor-with-arduino-uno)

Comment: To do this: *I need you to verify that the new circuit is correct.* means I have to ask this: what range of resistance is it intended to measure? Then I need to ask what range of output voltages are you hoping corresponds with what level of moisture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will work. The resistor is used to supply a current from 5V to the soil between the probes. The current developes a voltage drop across the soil from one probe to the other. This is then measured by the Arduino on the analog output pins. The capacitor averages the voltage somewhat for a steadier reading.

Comment: What about capacitor C1? Is he really necessary?

Comment: Yes it is necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much!